# Android ProGuard return Line Number

Tags: java, android, apk, proguard

Is there a way to get ProGuard to return a line number where the crash happened?
I can use `retrace` to get to the method, but often for things like `NullPointerException` there are too many possibilities and in a large piece of code its extremely hard to determine the underlying cause as you have to check every object and it's life cycle to make sure nothing is wrong. It would really help if ProGuard could narrow this down to a line number for me.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Add this line to your proguard-project.txt file.

```
# will keep line numbers and file name obfuscation
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage

Comment: I can't find the proguard-project.txt file anywhere in my Android Studio solution. Where is it located??

Comment: @MikeKeskinov, see `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile`, there you will find file names. If it doesn't exist, create one. Probably it's `proguard-rules.pro`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Android project, it tell you about which lines you might want to uncomment:

```
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

So, you should consider having these:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

However, note that for some reason, Firebase Crashlytics team told me this line might interfere with their service:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

so you might not see good information of crashes stack trace if you use it.

Comment: I was going to ask that, thank you so much for this info. DO you know if I do not use this line `-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile` would that cause a problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Hilal I decided not to use `-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile`

Comment: "-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile" will rename original file names. So if you got line number without its file name, you got nothing

Comment: So, it's good without it, right?