# Google Play Developer Console not deobfuscating stack trace

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I just published my first app (in beta). I used the default proguard settings in my `build.gradle` (I didn't change the `proguard-rules.pro` file):

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

I uploaded the `mapping.txt` to the Google Play Developer Console. But now I have a stack trace that is not (or only partially?) deobfuscated.  `com.vandelay_software.friendmap` is the package name of my app.

I have a second stack trace for a different problem where my class and method names have been deobfuscated, just the line numbers are missing.

Should I adjust some settings in `proguard-rules.pro`? Or am I doing something else wrong?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the link regarding the line numbers. But my first question still remains: why did the Google Play Developer Console not deobfuscate my stack trace, even though I uploaded the `mapping.txt`? It is the correct file, because I was able to deobfuscate manually using `retrace.sh`.

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
at com.facebook.b.t.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.n.f(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.vandelay_software.friendmap.a.d.b(Unknown Source)
at com.vandelay_software.friendmap.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.vandelay_software.friendmap.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.vandelay_software.friendmap.view.FriendMapActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
... 10 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode ProGuard's obfuscated code precisely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182300/how-to-decode-proguards-obfuscated-code-precisely)

Comment: Thanks! I would've thought the default settings would keep the line numbers...