# Google Play Console Stack Trace

Tags: java, android, google-play, stack-trace

In Google Play Console, I am getting the below exception trace. Although I have added deobfuscation files, the line numbers are being displayed as 0.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.ae.apps.common.managers.ContactManager.getContactIdFromAddress(ContactManager.java:0)
  at com.ae.apps.messagecounter.utils.MessageCounterUtils.sortThisMap(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at <OR>.getMessageCountDegrees(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at <OR>.getContactMessageList(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at <OR>.convertAddressToContact(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at <OR>.getIndexFromDate(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at <OR>.getWeekStartDate(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at <OR>.getMessageLimitValue(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at <OR>.getCycleSentCount(MessageCounterUtils.java:0)
  at com.ae.apps.messagecounter.activities.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:0)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

I dont't understand what this `<OR>` statements in the stack trace. The `ContactManager.getContactIdFromAddress()` is only called from the method `MessageCounterUtils.convertAddressToContact()`.

How to properly understand this stack trace?

I believe I have added the necessary Null checks in the above method anyways.

https://github.com/midhunhk/ae-apps-library/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ae/apps/common/managers/ContactManager.java#L377

Comment: Can you post your proguard config? Does it keep line numbers?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that I'm using the default proguard file.

Comment: Looks like the same issue+solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158849/android-proguard-return-line-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're running into the same issue answered in this question: [Android ProGuard return Line Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158849/android-proguard-return-line-number)

Proguard doesn't keep the line numbers by default.

Answer (score 1):

> How to properly understand this stack trace?

< OR > literally means "OR". When stack trace is created for some lines of it there are several possibilities (LineNumberTable is missing or it is corrupted?) so they are printed with this prefix.