# Strange stacktrace reported by Google Play Console

Tags: android, stack-trace, google-play-console

I'm getting this kind of `stacktraces` in the crash reports provided by Google Play Console:

```
  at com.example.ClassA.createInstance (ClassA.java)
  or                     .op1(ClassA.java)
  or                     .op2(ClassA.java)
  or                     .op3 (ClassA.java)
  or                     .op4 (ClassA.java)
```

Does anybody knows why are `"or"(s)` in the `stacktrace`? 
I'm guessing is something about the code obfuscation.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Console Stack Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154256/google-play-console-stack-trace)