# Google Play Console Crash Reports - multiple ORs

Tags: android, google-play-console, bug-reporting

Why the Google Play Console of my Production app crash reports (located in "Android Vitals" / "ANR and Crashes" and then select any crash to see a stack trace) contains a lot of **ORs** in the Stack Trace?

What does it mean? Which of that 12 methods actually caused the crash? Why the report so unclear?

Is there a way to get exact method name and ideally the line number in the report? (I have added mapping file under "Deobfuscation files").

[image]

Comment: maybe you're using multiple `mapping.txt` files I guess. I am not sure though.

Comment: May be some kind of issue for not enabling proguard. Did you try producing the error with proguard enabled? Note that minify and proguard are different

Comment: I'm not sure. minifyEnabled is true (in gradle). Where should I change proguard settings?

Comment: minifyEnabled true means your code will be optimized and shrinked. Using a proguard by mentioning the proguard rules in gradle helps in obfuscation of the code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using Proguard for minifying and obfuscating your code (so far so good), and Proguard reuses the same method names as much as it can (i.e. as long as the signature of the methods are different) to minimize the number of letters it has to use. So the minified code contains most likely a dozen of methods with the name "a" in each class, and the stacktrace only gives you the method name, not its signature, so it's unfortunately impossible to know which one of the dozen "a" methods is being called, hence the deobfuscation tool gives you all the possibilities.

You can customise the Proguard configuration to avoid so many conflicts and hence make it easier to debug for you, but that will be at the cost of your app's size.

Edit: Use the `-useuniqueclassmembernames` flag to avoid these ORs. You can check the [ProGuard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#shrinkingoptions) for more details.

Comment: Could you provide any information/instructions how to solve this problem (i.e. keep proGuard but get rid of ORs) - so we can see where exactly crash happens. Ideally to have line numbers too

Comment: Edited my response to answer your question.
Regarding line numbers, I think the flag is `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable`
More info can be found [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#stacktrace) -- search for "Producing useful obfuscated stack traces".
Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question some time ago:

[Strange stacktrace reported by Google Play Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608036/strange-stacktrace-reported-by-google-play-console).

In my case i could notice that only one of the functions in each group could be the right one beacause the others where not invoked inside the "above" function.

I think this is a protection method against reverse engineering.