# Missing line numbers at playstore crashdumps

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing some Android apps in kotlin, and playstore shows no line numbers at the crashdumps if using proguard. Anyone knows what can be the issue?

Edit: I'm uploading the mapping.txt file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently adding some new proguard rules fixed it.

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable
```

Comment: Did you uploaded the mapping.txt file after releasing your app?

Comment: ye I did, updated the question. Anyway it works now with the proguard rules, thanks

Comment: nevermind, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158849/android-proguard-return-line-number